# How to determine when rectangle and rotated rectangle intersect using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, collision

For my application, I have a SVG-drawn rectangle that I am using as a hitbox and I'm looking to make a JavaScript function that returns a boolean of true whenever the hitbox touches another rectangle that has been rotated about its centre by some angle using CSS transformations. I have discovered this code from http://www.inkfood.com/collision-detection-with-svg/:

```
function intersectRect(r1, r2) {
var r1 = r1.getBoundingClientRect();    //BOUNDING BOX OF THE FIRST OBJECT
var r2 = r2.getBoundingClientRect();    //BOUNDING BOX OF THE SECOND OBJECT

//CHECK IF THE TWO BOUNDING BOXES OVERLAP
 return !(r2.left > r1.right || 
       r2.right < r1.left || 
       r2.top > r1.bottom ||
       r2.bottom < r1.top);
}
```

This works great for regular rectangles, but I am unsure how to build upon this to work with my rotated rectangle. When I inspect the rotated rectangle using developer tools in my web browser, I can see that it highlights the rectangle correctly. That being said, when I try to extract the bounding client rectangle using JavaScript, it returns the dimensions of the rectangle in its unrotated form. My question is how do I receive the correct dimensions for my rotated rectangle so I can detect when it collides with my hitbox rectangle? Is there another method for me to detect when my hitbox touches my rotated rectangle? Any help would be much appreciated.
[image]

Comment: If you're open to using `canvas` instead, you're probably going to have an easier time. `isPointInPath` in particular may save you a lot of headaches: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_ispointinpath.asp

Comment: @jmcgriz Thanks for your response! I'm playing around with the canvas on W3Schools, and I can see that isPointInPath seems to work perfectly in the rectangle that I draw without rotation. However, after rotation, it does not seem to trigger true when a point inside of it is given. I've tried using lineTo() as well, but it only works on the actual thin line itself, and when I increased the lineWidth, it still only works on the original line, not on the new stroke area. Is there a way to overcome this in either case?

Comment: I'm going to mess with it a little, but I think your answer's going to come from actually tracing the rectangle and using a transformation matrix for the rotations instead of just using the built in `rect` and `rotate` methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of ick in the SVG spec, but here is a working example of what you requested. Be warned, this is gotcha central!!

https://codepen.io/josephscottstevens/pen/XEgbrP

```
window.onmousemove = function(e) {
  var c = document.getElementById("circle");
  var l = document.getElementById("line");
  var displayDiv = document.getElementById("isColiding");
  var circle = { radius : c.r, center : { x:c.cx, y:c.cy } };
  var line =   { p1 : { x:l.x1, y:l.y1 }, p2 : { x:l.x2, y:l.y2 } };
  displayDiv.textContent = circle.radius; //(distance == 0) ? "coliding" : "not coliding";
  moveSection("circle", e.clientX - 20, e.clientY - 20);
  var distance = circleDistFromLineSeg(circle, line);


}
```

Comment: Very clever, but you're cheating a bit haha. Although this could potentially save a lot of processing power if you use two line segments as the bounds of the rectangle and can make use of a circular hitbox for your moving elements.

Comment: This is just what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Alright so this is going to take a lot of optimization before it's practical for your use case, but it does serve as a proof of concept that `isPointInPath` will work with a rotation, as long as you draw the rectangle by points (you can also use `fillRect` and `rotate` to draw it, and just trace the outline with `lineTo` but no `stroke` to create your bounding box to check against).

To test out the `isPointInPath`, edit the values of `checkX` and `checkY`

```js
var ctx = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d')

function rotate(x, y, a, b, degrees){
 let angle = degrees * (Math.PI / 180),
   sinA = Math.sin(angle),
   cosA = Math.cos(angle)
    
  return [
   cosA * (a - x) - sinA * (b - y) + x,
    sinA * (a - x) + cosA * (b - y) + y
  ]
}

function drawRect(x, y, w, h, rotation){
 var manipFn = rotation ? rotate : function(a,b){ return [a,b]; }
  
  var coords = {
   bottomLeft: manipFn(x,y,x,y,rotation),
    bottomRight: manipFn(x,y,x+w,y,rotation),
    topRight: manipFn(x,y,x+w,y+h,rotation),
    topLeft: manipFn(x,y,x,y+h,rotation)
  }
  
  var checkX = 106,
    checkY = 18
  
  ctx.moveTo(...coords.bottomLeft)
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#3a1"
  ctx.lineWidth = 1
  ctx.lineTo(...coords.bottomRight)
  ctx.lineTo(...coords.topRight)
  ctx.lineTo(...coords.topLeft)
  ctx.lineTo(...coords.bottomLeft)
  console.log(ctx.isPointInPath(checkX,checkY))
  ctx.stroke()
  ctx.closePath()
  
  ctx.fillStyle = "#000"
  ctx.fillRect(checkX, checkY, 2, 2)
}


//drawRect(10, 10, 20, 30)


drawRect(100, 10, 20, 30, 45)
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```